# Put an array into ckeckbox field symfony2

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, symfony-2.3

I have a question. It's possible to send an array in checkbox?
For example I have the array :

```
public static $aColors = array(
    '1' => 'white',
    '2' => 'black',
    '3' => 'yellow',
    '4' => 'red',
    '5' => 'green',
    '6' => 'blue',
);
```

Now I want to send this array in a checkbox, I tried like this :

```
->add('colors', 'checkbox', array('mapped' => false, 'choices'   => Colors::aColors));
```

But I can't. Help me please. Thx in advance.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is `serialize`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
 ->add('colors', 'choice', array('mapped' => false, 'choices'   => array(
                                              '1' => 'white',
                                              '2' => 'black',
                                              '3' => 'yellow',
                                              '4' => 'red',
                                              '5' => 'green',
                                              '6' => 'blue',
                                       ), 'expanded' => TRUE,
                                          'multiple' => TRUE
                                      ));
```

It will convert your choice into checkbox .

Comment: I get radiobuttons with this example not checkboxes

Comment: See the updated answer right now .. , also include multiple = true .